# Double Relay with Office365/Exchange

Tags: email, exchange, smtp, office365, proofpoint

REF: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/195850/sending-emails-out-via-proofpoint-exchangeoffice365

This is what I have in my Office365 setup.

[image]

I was looking at the headers when I sent to a GMAIL address and I see it coming from Office365 but nothing like it's coming from ProofPoint nor do I see the emails being sent from SalesForce being logged in ProofPoints logs.

What am I not doing correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you might need a transport rule to make emails make certain users or email addresses to use  the connector.

For example any email coming from noreply@domain.on should use the x connector?